# Delphi Undeclared identifier ansistring

Tags: delphi

I use delphi xe8.

I get an error when compile my programm on step

> CyrStr = type AnsiString(1251)
>
> "Undeclared identifier ansistring"

What library I need to use?

Comment: Why do you feel compelled to use ansi code pages?

Comment: You can get them back with Andy's ByteStrings patch: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/04/byte-strings-for-xe8s-mobile-compilers/  but one wonders if you really should be doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably compiling for a target that doesn't support AnsiString. The mobile compilers don't support AnsiString while the desktop compilers do.

Comment: It's strange. i made a new vcl programm with this code. It works. I also made a new multiform programm. It also works.

Comment: It's not strange. It's documented that this is so.

Comment: @AndyBirtman: Desktop compilers (Windows and OSX, both VCL and FMX) support AnsiString. Mobile compilers (iOS and Android) do not. [Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop): "*Code that uses any of the following **unsupported types** should either be eliminated or rewritten to use an alternate type: WideString, **AnsiString**, ShortString, **AnsiChar**, **PAnsiChar**, PWideChar, Openstring*"